# Triggering a class method in an eventhandler

Tags: javascript, event-handling

```
class Controller {

    constructor(names){
        this.names = names;
    }

    sayhello(name){
        console.log("Hello " + name);
    }

    makeLink() {
        this.names.forEach(function(name){
            var link = document.createElement('li');
            link.innerHTML = name;
            var container = document.getElementById('container');
            container.appendChild(link);
            link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                sayhello(event.target.innerText);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do in my actual code. I want to trigger the class method 'sayhello' when the 'li' is clicked, so that that it prints out the name corresponding to the 'li'. However, it doesn't seem to be working. I tried searching for a solution but still haven't had any luck finding it. Does anyone know how I might make this work?

Comment: Its `this.sayhello`, not `sayhello`.

Comment: You should have a look at [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 2):

`sayhello` does not exist in `makeLink`s' scope, but in its context ( aka `this`), so you have to take care to not loose context through that forEach `function`, then you can easily access it:

```
makeLink() {
    this.names.forEach((name) => { // <----
        var link = document.createElement('li');
        link.innerHTML = name;
        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        container.appendChild(link);
        link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            this.sayhello(event.target.innerText); // <----
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I'm pretty new to this, but what is the main difference between calling it as '()=>{ }' and 'function(){ }' in general.

Comment: @christine glad to help :)

Comment: @christine: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196